# Pythonic way to make string dependend on type of variable

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-logic

In a text file I have to write values, and next to each value either `"NUMERIC"` if the value's type is `int` or `float`, or `"NOMINAL"`, if the type is `str`.
I know that this could be solved by an `if` statement, but I would be pleased to use a more elegant way. I thought of multiplication with a boolean - something like that:

```
outputfile.write(value1 + "_NOMINAL" * (type(value1) is str)
                        + "_NUMERIC" * (type(value1) is (float or int)))
```

This does not work - I don't know why... It works if I change the second expression into two conditions:

```
+ "_NUMERIC" * ((type(value1) is float) or (type(value1) is int))
```

Is there any other elegant, pythonic approach to get this done?

Comment: The first one doesn't work because `(float or int)` resolves to `float`.

Comment: `is (float or int)` doesn't do what you think it does. Perhaps you meant `in ( float, int)`.

Comment: Your code can't possibly work. You should get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'` if value1 is ever an int.

Comment: "Is there any other elegant, pythonic approach to get this done?" for the simple case you've provided I'd say an `if` is the most elegant way. If your actual use is more complicated (this kinda looks like lexical tokenizing) you might get more pleasing results from a `Token` class and subclasses that have appropriate `str` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really think this is elegant (a matter of taste, I guess), try:

```
outputfile.write(value1 + "_NOMINAL" * (type(value1) is str)
                        + "_NUMERIC" * (type(value1) in (float, int)))
```

If you ask me, I think I'd write it like this (assuming the value would only be a string or a number):

```
print >> outputfile, value1, "NOMINAL" if type(value1) is str else "NUMERIC"
```

or, if you want to allow for values that are elements of subclasses of `str`:

```
print >> outputfile, value1, "NOMINAL" if isinstance(value1, str) else "NUMERIC"
```

If there were more things changing, depending on the type of the value, or if there were more than two types, I'd use an `if`.

Comment: would you rather use an `if` statement? I am still a beginner with python and try to learn about good style, too.